# How to open a new Activity from a tab?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabbed-activity

My project has three tabs.
I want to open a new Activity from one tab

My Java current tab Activity

```
package com.example.muhsin.tabstes;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by muhsin on 22/07/17.
 */
public class Tab2Feeds extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2feed, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

layout:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="open new"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="204dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="112dp" />
```

Then I create a new empty Activity called profile Activity

```
package com.example.muhsin.tabstes;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
    }
}
```

How to navigate from Tab2Feeds to ProfileActivity?

Comment: You want the tab itself to open a new activity? Or a button on the fragment to open a new activity?

Comment: on click of the button open new activity (no tabs inside new activity )

Comment: your current tab activity is not an activity its fragment or is that fragment is your tab? if so than simply add click listener to button and call activity.

Comment: tried but its giving error cannot resolve symbol findviewbyid(int), cannot resolve symbol 'button'

Answer (score 1):

To start activity from Fragment:

put your code in onCreateView method or onViewCreated method:

```
 Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (getActivity() != null) { // check if activity not null
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ProfileActivity.class);
                    getActivity().startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: yes import these. on intent press ALT+Enter and select intent

Comment: You can Accept this as an Answer. It will be beneficial to others

Comment: definitely  i'll

Answer (score 0):

In your Tab2Feeds Fragment, get a reference to the button by calling `finViewById`. 
From there set a clicklistener with `setOnClickListener`.

Finally use an `Intent` to open the new activity.
You will need a `Context` which is gotten by calling `getActivity()`

```
    Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ProfileActivity.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

A the top of the file dont forget your imports

```
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;
```

Comment: its giving error like cannot resolve symbol 'button' , cannot resolve symbol findviewbyid(int) pls check the screenshot http://i.imgur.com/hRUlSJY.png

Comment: sorry, i forgot its a fragment, you probably need `rootView.findViewById `

Comment: you need to import them

Comment: ok thanks i'll make this accepted when i get reputation currently i'm having less than 15 reputation

Comment: Just a hint, the Upvote feature is unlocked at 15 reps. You can accept an answer at any point by clicking the check mark next to the answer.